# input[type='text'] CSS selector does not apply to default-type text inputs?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The default input type is 'text'. I have always assumed then that CSS declarations targeting `input[type='text']` would affect those inputs even if the type was not explicitly declared on the control. However, I just noticed that my default-type text inputs do not get the styles. Why is this the case? And how can I address this?

```css
input[type='text'] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input name='t1' type='text' /> /* Is Red */
<input name='t1' /> /* Is Not Red */
```

Comment: CSS selectors target the attribute on the tag and not its default assumption.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The CSS uses only the data in the DOM tree, which has little to do with how the renderer decides what to do with elements with missing attributes.

So either let the CSS reflect the HTML

```
input:not([type]), input[type="text"]
{
background:red;
}
```

or make the HTML explicit.

```
<input name='t1' type='text'/> /* Is Not Red */
```

If it didn't do that, you'd never be able to distinguish between

```
element { ...properties... }
```

and

```
element[attr] { ...properties... }
```

because all attributes would always be defined on all elements. (For example, `table` always has a `border` attribute, with `0` for a default.)

Comment: `input:not([type]), input[type="text"]` to cover both cases.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes; I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Never knew about `input:not([type])` selector- solves my problem right there

Comment: I would argue that it is mostly an HTML/DOM problem, rather than a CSS one. In HTML, `<table><tr></tr><table>` implicitly becomes `<table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>`, so it is quite strange that `<input>` does not implicitly become `<input type="text">` in the DOM.

Comment: @Kal Not strange; those are simply different cases. The definition of HTML is very precise about this: the `tbody` element is defined  specifically as being mandatory, but having an optional start tag. Or in other words, the tbody is there, even if you don't have `<tbody>` in your HTML source. The `type` attribute in `input` on the other hand, is not mandatory. And the behaviour of `input` without `type` happens to be the same as `input` with `type='text`, but that is coincidental, and that has nothing to do with the DOM tree.

Comment: @MrLister In my opinion, that's just technicality. And my point was exactly that the "definition of HTML" is strange. From the perspective of people who need to write CSS, this probably feels self-inconsistent:
`table>tbody>tr` would select `<table><tr><tr></table>`, but `input[type="text"]` wouldn't select `<input>`.

Comment: @BoltClock, Doesn't match the **text input** element when the value of its `type` string has other characters (like whitespace and invalid chars).

Comment: @Pacerier The value of the `type` attribute is not supposed to have other characters like whitespace and invalid chars. And the author of the css is not obliged to provide for typos in the HTML.

Comment: @MrLister, It's not supposed to have, but it *happens*. I'm saying Note well that there **will** still be input text elements not matched by the rules above.

Comment: @Pacerier And I replied, **the author of the css is not obliged to provide for typos in the HTML** and I stand by that. Errors in the HTML should be corrected, not masked away by CSS.

Comment: @MrLister, To which I'd replied: "but it happens, so note there will still be input text elements not matched by the rules above".

Answer (score 8):

Because, it is not **supposed to** do that.

`input[type=text] { }` is an attribute selector, and will only select those element, with the matching attribute.

Answer (score 7):

By CSS specifications, browsers may or may not use information about default attributes; mostly the don’t. The relevant clause in the CSS 2.1 spec is [5.8.2 Default attribute values in DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#default-attrs). In CSS 3 Selectors, it’s clause [6.3.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#def-values), with the same name. It recommends: “Selectors should be designed so that they work whether or not the default values are included in the document tree.”

It is generally best to explicitly specify essential attributes such as `type=text` instead of defaulting them. The reason is that there is no simple reliable way to refer to the `input` elements with defaulted `type` attribute.

Comment: +1, notice how the word "must" is never used anywhere in this section (except within an example to describe a different cascading issue).

Comment: What is important is **actual browser behavior**. And it seems that no browser does that.....

Answer (score 0):

To be compliant with all browsers you should always declare the input type.

Some browsers will assume default type as 'text', but this isn't a good practice.

Comment: This answers the question how?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 input[type='text']
 {
   background:red !important;
 }
```